# Create GenericType<list> but list entry type is available as GenericType itself

Tags: java, json, generics, java-7, generic-programming

This Java problem is best explained by giving a code example:

```
void  <T extends A> process(GenericType<T> listEntryType)
{
    // ...
    deserializeJson(data, new GenericType<List</* listEntryType */>>);
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create `GenericType`-object for a `List`, but the list's entry type is only available as a `GenericType` itself. But how can I achieve this? I don't know by what `/* listEntryType */` in the example has to be replaced.

This is a simplification of my actual problem. Here is some information about the actual problem, for those who are interested:

Actually the object is not contained in a `List` but in a `Map`. You can see that `T` must extend class `A`. This means:

The caller of `process()` only knows that he wants to process data of type `T` (`listEntryType`), but he doesn't know about the structure of the data which contains this object.

The method `process()` knows the structure of the data and knows the exact location of an instance of a subclass of `A`, but doesn't know the concrete type of it.

I know that I can solve the problem easily by changing the parameter of `process()` to `GenericType<List<T>>`, but I don't want the caller to know about the structure of the data.

Comment: Can't do because Java doesn't do type inference on nested type parameters.

Comment: Do you need the generics? Could you just use `A` instead of `T` throughout?

Comment: The JSON deserializer has to know which concrete subclass of `A` is being contained by the JSON data.

Comment: `GenericType<List<T>> type = new GenericType<List<T>>(){};
deserializeJson(data, type);`

Comment: No johnnynemonic that won't work even if it compiles. The deserializer just receives the information that the structure contains any instance of a subclass of `A`. But it doesn't know which concrete class. As it doesn't know which subclass it just tries to deserialize into an instance of `A` itself (and fails, because I declared `A` as abstract ;-) )

Comment: Use listEntryType.getType()  as parameter of GenericType ==> type = new GenericType<List<T>>(listEntryType.getType()){}; that should propagate the type of the class passed in the param of process(GenericType<T> listEntryType) to the new genericType